# Rails: Paypal Express implementation fails with undefined method `checkout_thank_you_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, activemerchant, shopify-activemerchant

I am working on the integration of Paypal Express payments. I am adapting a Standard checkout and I am using the active-merchant gem. Set up should be something like `response=gateway.setup_purchase(price, details)`, where details are all the parameter which PayPal requires. The express gateway requires a return_url and cancel_return_url.

When I try to execute the payment through a submit button I get:

```
Order xx failed with error message undefined method `checkout_thank_you_url' for #<Order:0x1081e1bb8>
```

In my order model I have the following parts:

```
#app/models/order.rb

def process
  process_with_active_merchant
  save!
  self.status == 'processed'
end

private
def process_with_active_merchant
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
  gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new( 
    :login     => 'sandbox-account', 
    :password  => 'sandbox-password', 
    :signature => "sandbox-secret"

    params = { 
    :order_id => self.id, 
    :email => email, 
    :address => { :address1 => ship_to_address, 
                  :city => ship_to_city, 
                  :country => ship_to_country, 
                  :zip => ship_to_postal_code 
                } , 
    :description => 'Books', 
    :ip => customer_ip,
    :return_url => checkout_thank_you_url(@order), # return here if payment success
    :cancel_return_url => checkout_index_url(@order) # return here if payment failed
}
  response = gateway.setup_purchase((@order.total * 100).round(2), params)
  if response.success? 
    self.status = 'processed' 
  else 
    self.error_message = response.message 
    self.status = 'failed' 
  end 
end
```

The method is called in the checkout controller

```
def place_order
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
  @order.customer_ip = request.remote_ip 
  populate_order
  ...
  @order.process
  ...
end

def thank_you
 ...
end
```

How can I get this to work? Thank you in advance!

## Update

I suppose I have to specify the controller and action, but when using:

```
:return_url => url_for(:controller => :checkout, :action => "thank_you")
```

I get:

```
Order 98 failed with error message undefined method `url_for' for #<Order:0x1065471d8>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Oder model, include the module that Rails uses to generate URLs.

Add this code inside your class definition for Order:

```
class Order  
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers  
  # ...
end
```

Those helpers are already included in Controller classes, so methods like `checkout_thank_you_url` are available in controllers (and hence view templates) by default.

You must include the module into any other classes where you want to use route methods.

Comment: Thank you for your input. That was new to me. Unfortunately both `:return_url => checkout_success_url(self.id, :only_path => true)` as well as `:return_url => url_for(:controller => "checkout", :action => "thank_you", :only_path => true, :id => self.id)` still get a `error_message = 'ReturnURL is invalid.. CancelURL is invalid.'` Any idea why?

Comment: Well now you have a new error!  Those error messages do not look like Rails-generated messages.  My guess is that they are coming from PayPal's API.  My suggestion would be to expand `return_url => url_for(...)` to two separate lines like:  `my_return_url = url_for(...)` and then in your call to PaypalExpressGateway.new send params using that variable like `return_url: my_return_url`.  That refactoring allows you to add a breakpoint where you can inspect `my_return_url` and see if it's the appropriate format.

Comment: That sounds very promising. The introduction of a second breaking point is perfect, since to me models are much more difficult to track. I postponed PayPal for a moment in order to finish the shipping routine – ajax is not working for don't know what reason – but as soon as I will have finished that part I will test your answer. Thank you very much!